# How "subjective" is "good-readability"?

Tags: style

How "subjective" is "good-readability"?

Are there quality studies that can explain this?

I'm confused about that I perceive that different people seem to have different preferences regarding:

- usability
- informativeness
- comprehension

Or something that someone else might claim "cryptic", might be "very clear" to someone else.

Comment: Worth pointing out, since it's not entirely clear from your question, that there are intended-to-be-objective readability scoring systems.  You might, if you are not already familiar with the topic, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch–Kincaid_readability_tests.

Answer (score 3):

Reading in-between the lines of your question, I'm guessing what you're looking for is how to objectively and concretely decide whether a piece of writing is Good or Bad, and how to measure the Goodness of writing. Or at least, you want to know whether such a thing is possible. Well, the answer is complicated. You *can* say whether a piece of writing is Good, but the argument you'd make would be neither objective nor subjective. It would be something else.

I get where this question is coming from. I work as a software developer, and in the math-y, science-y world of that field, questions like this make sense. Code that is Good runs without bugs, is easily maintained, and performs well. All of these things can be measured very concretely. There are right and wrong answers. And similar qualities show up in other STEM fields. A scientific theory is Good if it makes accurate predictions and provides a helpful explanation. A math theorem is Good if it is rigorous, correct, and elegantly communicates the intuition behind the solution. And so on.

If this is the world you're coming from, it's easy to ask whether something more subjective, like writing, can also have its Goodness measured. Or maybe it's completely subjective, and there's no such thing as objectively Good writing? Unfortunately, creative pursuits just don't work that way. You need to bring an entirely different mindset.

For a creative field like writing, there is indeed such a thing as Good and Bad work. But there's no concrete way to measure it. Instead, you have to understand the principles of what makes effective writing and be willing to analyze it from the component pieces, so to speak. And writing is a mixture of objectively right or wrong elements, like grammar and using correct facts instead of misinformation, and subjective elements, like voice and style. All of these elements are deeply intertwined - which facts you cite is a part of your voice, for example, and different styles use different grammar, sometimes even playing fast and loose with traditionally hard-set rules

So you can't *measure* the Goodness of a piece of writing. Instead, you need to *analyze* it.

A complete description of how to analyze writing is far too broad for this question. In fact, the entirety of Writing.SE is about figuring out how to write effectively and determine for oneself whether your writing is good! But I can describe how to get into the right mindset.

To start with, there are the objective parts of writing. Is your grammar correct? Are your facts correct and cited effectively? If you are writing in a context that adheres to a style guide, do you follow its guidelines? A piece that has severe issues in these areas can be harshly criticized because, like a scientific "theory" based on dangerous misinformation, the writing is clearly wrong from the outset.

Then there are elements that are somewhat subjective but can be easily smelled. You've touched on one of them in your question: We don't have a direct way to measure whether a piece of writing is clear, but there is a stark difference between a logically-organized, succinct piece of writing and a meandering mess. Similar qualities include whether the piece hits the right tone, whether it is structured sensibly, and whether the point being argued is effectively supported by the arguments presented. People can and will disagree about whether the same piece of writing has these qualities, but most good-faith readers will come away with mostly similar opinions of them.

And then there are the elements that are completely subjective. Did you find the style enjoyable? Do you agree with the argument being made, or in the case of fiction, did you enjoy the story? But even here, analysis has tools to make a case for a piece being Good or Bad not objectively per say, but in some kind of Platonic ideal sense. You might or might not care for romance literature, for example. But if you were tasked with writing a review for such a novel, you could discuss whether the story follows the expectations of the genre. Does it use the commonly-accepted story structure? Is the romance set up in a way so that the kind of people who enjoy that sort of thing are going to find themselves hot and bothered? Does it hit a fun, titillating, and enjoyably escapist tone? You wouldn't ask the same kinds of questions you'd ask about a piece of hard science fiction. You don't expect a romance novel to ask a compelling philosophical question about the future of technology, to explore the dynamics of societal change, or to ground itself firmly in what is scientifically possible.

The point of that example is: You can enjoy science fiction more than romance, or visa-versa. But both types of genre have well-established expectations. And when you analyze a piece of fiction from the point of view of those genres, subjective questions of enjoyability and engagement move into the previous category of things that aren't objective per say, but are close enough for you to make confident arguments about them nevertheless. You can analyze the subjective aspects of non-fiction writing in a similar way. An essay in the New Yorker, for example, is going to be expected to take a significantly more playful and colorful tone, almost like a piece of fiction, than would be appropriate in a scientific paper or corporate memo. And an article written to an audience that believes in a particular religion can start from the assumption that the religion is true in a way that would be totally unconvincing in a paper published in a secular academic journal.

Altogether, this is the mindset you need to decide whether a piece of writing is usable and informative and comprehendible:

- There are some aspects, like grammar and correct information, that are concretely right or wrong, and you absolutely should treat them accordingly.
- There are other aspects like clarity and structure that aren't quite objective, but there's a clear difference between effective and ineffective writing that an experienced writer or discerning reader will be able to pick up on.
- And there are aspects that are subjective. In these cases, you can simply say whether you enjoy them for yourself. But if you want to say whether these aspects are handled effectively or not in a more concrete sense, you need to be willing to analyze the writing for what it's trying to accomplish and the genre or context it sits in, even if that context isn't something that's normally your preference.

Good writing is neither subjective nor objective. It is effective. And as you continue your journey into being a better reader and writer yourself, you will become more intimately familiar and discerning about the elements that give rise to effective writing.

Comment: I'm not sure if your usage of "effective writing" is as clear as you seem to imply. Effectiveness should be relative to at least: -audience/reader, -goals, -conservativeness in usage of resources. A "good to read paper" that has wasteful research methodology is not effective. A good to read paper that's not accessible except for some small expert circle is not effective (or is it?)? A good and well-written research that's not reproducible is not effective.

Answer (score 0):

Completely subjective, books that I won't even pick up because I find the writing style literally makes me throw up, I'm looking at you Brandon Sanderson, are lauded by critics and top best seller lists year-on-year. There is literally no accounting for taste, you can't quantify personal responses to written works at best you can generalise to a target population demographic. You also can't quantify personal intuition when it comes to mystery plots etc... dad realised what was happening in *The Village* about half an hour in the first time he watched it but I've met people who don't understand it having watched the whole film. I've read stories on the recommendation that they're "really twisty" only to be bored for most of the narrative because I worked the whole story out after the third chapter. I've been told a movie is "nice and simple" by the same person  only to be pleasantly surprised by the complexity of the plot.

Comment: "I find the writing style literally makes me throw up," Wow, I'm sorry that happens to you! Is there a medical name for that? :P

Comment: @DM_with_secrets Not that I know of.

Comment: That throwing up must be embarrassing in a bookshop!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That would be much of the reason not to pick up said books.

Answer (score 0):

Reading comprehension can be trained. Knowledge can be gained.

If you read a lot, with time your ability to quickly comprehend the kind of text you read a lot increases. Also, with reading a lot, you become more and more familiar with the ideas and concepts used in certain types of texts (e.g. philosophical essays or biological journal articles) so that there is an increasing difference between a trained reader both in reading comprehension as well as in specialist knowledge, which eplains why some people may find one specific text "very clear" and another person, who hasn't read much and encounters that type of text for the first time, finds it "cryptic".

But disregarding individual differences in reading comprehension and expert knowledge, there has been a lot of research into text difficulty and accessibility, and certain measures have been developed. Commonly they use lexical, syntactic, and textual criteria to assess difficulty. For example, you count how many of the words in the text are common words (and, house, father) and how many of the words are less common (benign, conceptualize, verdant). Texts with many less common words are considered more difficult. Then you consider the complexity of the syntactical structures. Are there many long and convoluted sentences? Is there a lot of indirect speech? The more complex the syntax, the more difficult a text is thought to be. Finally, the textual complexity is assessed. Does the text present a linear narrative of chronological events or a discontinuous discussion of different complex arguments?

These measures are "objective" in the sense that they are easy to apply to different texts and will return objective results (such as word counts). There is software that "measures" textual difficulty in this way. The results of these measures are evaluated by comparing them to human experiences with the same texts. For example, a sample of texts will be read by a number of probands, who then have to answer questions about the text. The more these probands understand, the easier the text is. These subjective results are compared to the automated measures, to validate them.

In the end, if you have a good, validated automated tool, you can predict pretty accurately how difficult a text will be for the average reader. There will of course always be well-trained readers who will find the text easier than your measure says, and people who rarely read who will find it more difficult, but over a representative sample of readers from trained to untrained, that measure will correspond quite well to the average reading experience.

These tools are used to asses texts for specific target audiences, such as children or the general public, for example when you want to publish information and want it to be understood not only be experts.

If you want to learn more, just google, "text difficulty" or some such, you will get a lot of results.